# Controller method is not called when I pass an array of objects in Ajax call with more than 81 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to call a controller method by Ajax like this:

```js
$.get("@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")",
     {
        groupID: Id,
        namePt: pt,
        nameEn: en,
        nameFr: fr,
        nameAr: ar,
        selectedProducts: listProd
      },
      function success(data) {
        //do something
      }).fail(function() {
        //do something
      });
```

I fill the listProd with values (products IDs) from a drop down list.

The problem is when the listProd contains more than 81 items... the controller method is not called and no error is displayed.

When the listProd contains 81 items or less, all works fine.

Is there a size limit to a list in ajax call?

Comment: Answer via Google: [Maximum length of an HTTP GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: In other words, you should be using POST, not GET.

Comment: If you do require an http get (If you access a resource and you don't modify anything, the post verb can be misleading), you can modify the maximum size of Get requests in your web server's configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use $.post instead $.get